# JQuery validate Rules comparing fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to add a rule using jquery validate.js to compare two textbox values ...?,

For required field i use something like this

```
   <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('[id$=txtname]').rules("add", {
                 required: true,
                 messages: {
                     required: "fill this"
                 }
             });
         });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id$=txtname]').rules("add", {
             required: true,
             messages: {
                 required: "fill this"
             }
});
//for the textbox you want to compare with 
$('[id$=txtname2]').rules("add", {
             equalTo: '#txtname',
             messages: {
                 required: "values not does not match."
             }
});
```

Comment: @Thanks kvc, this is what i'm looking for. 
But have as small problem here,

Instead of   
equalTo: '#txtname',

i need to do a ends with /contains  something like
equalTo: $('[id$=txtname]')

Comment: One thing I want to tell about this solution is that, I was looking for this solution since last 3 days. And your answer works for me. It's just like as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#<%= Email.ClientID %>').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    email: true
});
$('#<%= EmailConfirm.ClientID %>').rules('add', {
    equalTo: '#<%= Email.ClientID %>',
    messages: {
        required: 'adeda',
        equalTo: 'olá mundo'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using equalTo method

```
rules: { 
    TextBox1: 'required', 
    Textbox2: { 
        equalTo: '#Textbox1' 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks  pavan, but i would like to have it in the format  i specified, ( bcos name of the textbox field is getting rendered dynamically thru asp.net). i would only be able to specify as name ending with.